# physicalDirectory and Redirection in azure

Tags: azure

My .csdef file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="SimpleAzure1.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2012-10.1.8">
  <WebRole name="SimpleAzure1" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web2" physicalDirectory="../../../SimpleAzure1/">

        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="Endpoint2" hostHeader="SimpleAzure1.cloudapp.net" />

        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="http" port="80"></InputEndpoint>
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

And my project structure is:

[image: Structure]

I define `physicalDirectory="../../../SimpleAzure1/"` in `.csdef`  but when I create a package and deploy in azure physicalDirectory's  `default.aspx` page is not loaded.Its load a page from `asp.net wepappliaction`.When I define `physicalDirectory` in `.csdef` file why `asp.net wepappliaction` page is loading.Am I missing some thing.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one site in your web role then there is no need to specify the physical directory or the host header.I suspect the builder is taking some short cuts.  Try removing the site from the role and adding it again and this time leave the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Concur with knightpfhor - if you only have one site, remove the physical directory and host header.

If you are using more than one site in the role, deployment changed from SDK 1.7 to 1.8:

> The physicalDirectory attribute path is relative to the directory in
>   which the target Service Definition file resides when packaged. In
>   previous versions this file was located within the root project
>   directory. In this version, by default, this file is located in the
>   project output directory. You may need to update the relative path to
>   reflect the new location of the target Service Definition file.

To see where the files are actually located, enable remote access and RDP into the instance.  Check the Physical Directory specified in IIS and then confirm that path exists and references the installed website, typically E:\sitesroot\0 or F:\sitesroot\0